# site collections visibility problem

Tags: 2010, site-collection, content-database

I have a SharePoint 2010 site that I believe is using the included SQL version instead of the 2008 R2 that I had installed so my DB size limit appears to be 4gb.

I have created a second content DB called `WSS_Content_2`. When attempting to move one of my larger site collections, I get the message that it doesn't exist.

I then did a `Get-SPSite` which is only showing me sites that people have started using this:  `bufsdshpnt1/my/personal/username`.

I am a farm administrator and a domain admin.

Why can't I see the rest of my sites to be able to move one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean, you install the SharePoint with SQL Express edition rather using the complete SQL Server, right? where you created the 2nd content DB, on express edition or 2008 R2? from central admin, can you see all the site collections?

Comment: No I can't - but all the sites are up and active

Comment: I have 15 sites that show up if I click on the sites link on my sharepoint site.

Comment: how many web applications you have and what type of these sites are? from Cnetral admin > application management >view all site collections, what you see here?  Central admin > application Management > Content Database what you see ehre?

Comment: under manage web applications I have sharepoint - 80 and the sharepoint central admin

Comment: under site collections it shows sites that are /my/personal/usernames

Comment: what command you run to move the site collections? also if you click on the databases (wss_content, _2) are both on the same server?

Comment: Yes they are both on the same server.

Comment: Which site collection and what command you are using?

Comment: I used Move-SPSite <http://bufsdshpnt1/Sites/sanctuary> -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content_2

Comment: could you please give me the exact command and error

Comment: Ok, I will run it again

Comment: I have added pic to initial post with powershell command and error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22870/discussion-between-stephen-hathaway-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).

Comment: i am not seeing this site in the screen shot  "bufsdshpnt1/Sites/sanctuary", can you browse to this url?

Comment: I had the URL wrong, the site I browse to is http://bufsdshpnt1/sanctuary/SitePages/Home.aspx.  I tried the http://bufsdshpnt1/sanctuary in the move-spsite command and I get the same basic error and I still don't see it listed on the central administration view site collections page

Comment: again, this is not site collection, for me its look like a subsite under the "/" site collection.\

Comment: Ok, so I have one site, with several subsites then, is there a way to move subsites to another content database?

Comment: No, you  cannot move the subsite to different content DB, You have to move the site collection( which include all subsites, list, libraries).

Comment: is there a way to move the whole site to another content database that is utilizing my full SQL 2008R2 instead of the express so I don't have the space restrictions?

Comment: check my anwser.

Answer (score 0):

From your information, its look like you trying to move the subsite into different content database. which is not possible, you should move the site collection from one DB to other. Now, if you want to move the subsite into own db then:

- Move subsite to own site collection first, using export & import process.
- Now move new site collection to different DB.
- read this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/356985/Moving-a-Sharepoint-Sub-Site-to-its-own-Site-Colle
- But this process will have own limitations.

Another thing, what i understand due to sql express limitation you want to move them.If you have the regular SQL server then

- create new database on the new sql server from Central admin
- Now run the move-spsite with DB name and Dbserver name
- test it.

Comment: Ok, I will look at this and see what I can come up with.